# Trigonometry application in a problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

The answer to the question is 15 degrees. I would like to know if it is possible to solve by trigonometry. If so, how?

Law of sines and other things, but how to do without using a calculator?

Comment: Use Sine law or try trigonometric form of Ceva's theorem https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/TrigCeva.shtml

Comment: @MathLover Law of sines and other things, but how to do without using a calculator?

Answer (score 1):

Let BC=1.

1. Apply the law of cosines to triangle OBC to find the lengths of OB and OC.
2. Since $\angle\text{BAC}=48$, apply the law of cosines to triangle ABC to find the lengths of AB and AC.
3. Finally, use the law of cosines with triangle AOB twice to first find the length of AO and then the value of $x$.

Comment: Does this arrive at the result without using a calculator?

Comment: Not necessarily. It sounds complicated to find the cosine of generally mentioned angles without a calculator (at least I think it is impossible unless the cosines cancel out each other during the action).